# Polymer Google Sheets integration CSS retention

Tags: css, google-sheets, polymer

I'm using Google Polymer to do Google Sheets integration. (I want specific cells from a Google Sheet to appear on a webpage. I need them to preserve CSS (bold, color, background-color, etc). Anyone know how to get the website to display the CSS from the Google Sheet?

Comment: How are you retrieving the GSheet info?

Comment: @Kriggs I published the Google Sheet using the File>Publish to the web dropdown menu. I got the key from the URL (see how here: http://bit.ly/1DpPmYp ). I put that in the HTML document and it pulled the cells from the Google Sheet using the instructions from Google here: (http://bit.ly/1yxN8jK), but it does not preserve colors or bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send along the cells contents the info about the cells format, and you'll have to format them in the HTML.

The format methods are - (all applicable in the same range as the getValues()):

```
getNumberFormats();
getVerticalAlignments();
getHorizontalAlignments();
getFontWeights();
getFontStyle();
getFontSizes();
getFontLines();
getFontFamilies();
getFontColors();
getBackgrounds();
```

All return double arrays, that have to be passed to the HTML, and treated in it.